# Conditions for Expectation of Ito Integral to have Expectation 0

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider the Ito stochastic process $$X_t = X_0 + \int_{0}^{t} a_s ds  + \int_{0}^{t} b_s dW_s$$

What conditions are necessary or sufficient (besides adaptability/measurability) to show that $$ E \left\lbrace \int_{0}^{t} b_s dW_s \right\rbrace = 0?$$

The main one I see is $$ E \left\lbrace \int_{0}^{t} b_s^2 ds \right\rbrace < \infty $$.

Are there any others that are sufficient or necessary? If the expectation isn't finite, can it still be true? I've only recently begun to learn about Ito integrals in more depth.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y_t=\int_0^t b_s dW_s$ in the Ito sense.  If $E(|Y_t|)<\infty$, then $Y_t$ forms a martingale. Martingales have constant expectation, which must be zero, since $Y_0=0$ a.s.

Comment: That makes sense. In practice though, how easy is it to show that $E(|Y_t|) < \infty ?$ That seems like a nontrivial thing since I'm not sure how one deals with the absolute value of a stochastic integral

Comment: @Brenton You wrote the practical condition: $b \in L^2(\Omega \times [0,T])$. Then the absolute value condition I mentioned follows from routine analysis techniques, along with the Ito isometry. I am not sure whether you can do anything else; indeed I have forgotten the most general conditions under which the stochastic integral is defined. In my SDE course we usually used conditions which were stronger than necessary (e.g. assuming that the diffusion matrix is bounded) for convenience.

Comment: Ah ok. So the condition you gave follows from the fact that $b \in L^2(\Omega$ x $[0,T])$? Unfortunately, I haven't gotten to take an SDE course yet (and it won't be offered for another year so trying to learn what I can in the meantime!)

Comment: @Brenton Yes. The only thing you need that is "special" to SDEs is the Ito isometry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_isometry